# Blank page on FB.ui feed dialog on Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I cant get the feed dialog to work in a proper way and cant find any good solution on google.

Here is my code:

```js
FB.ui({
 method: 'feed',
 name: 'The title',
 link: 'http://link.com',
 picture: 'http://link.com/image.jpg',
 caption: 'The caption',
 description: 'The description',
 redirect_uri: 'http://theapp.com/close-popup.html',
},
function(response) {
 if (response && response.post_id) 
  console.log("Share has been made!");
});
```

Problem:
After the share dialog the page stops on a white blank page on URL https://m.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/feed. I tried to add the redirect_uri for redirect to some kind of close page but it wont work.

Any ideas here?

**SOLUTION**

```js
FB.ui({
 method: 'feed',
    display: 'touch' //Works with Chrome iOS/Android, page/popup for desktop
 name: 'The title',
 link: 'http://link.com',
 picture: 'http://link.com/image.jpg',
 caption: 'The caption',
 description: 'The description',
 redirect_uri: 'http://theapp.com/close-popup.html',
},
function(response) {
 if (response && response.post_id) 
  console.log("Share has been made!");
});
```

Comment: Hello, did you manage to get this sorted eventually ?

Comment: @EyadAlama finally yes. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The method ui will use display: 'touch' as default on mobile devices, however Chrome on iOS and Android will not apply this so if you define display: 'touch' it will work in both Safari and Chrome for mobile. Another problem is that display: 'touch' will show mobile interface even on desktop so you have to define display with page or popup for desktop version.